# PHP Foreach loop interating over a single element?

Tags: php, foreach

Can someone explain what this is doing please?

```
foreach($_POST['Detail'] as $i_Detail => &$a_Detail)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course I get the prinicple of the `foreach`, but this looks to me like it's trying to iterate through a single element of an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what's actually happening here is this `foreach` loop is pulling the key and value into the loop. If we assume the variable `$_POST['detail']` is an array that looks like this:

```
$_POST['detail']['name'] = 'Joe';
$_POST['detail']['last'] = 'Smith';
```

When the foreach loop is called,

```
foreach($_POST['Detail'] as $i_Detail => &$a_Detail)
```

`$i_Detail` is the key of the array. So, in this case on the first pass it would be name and on the following pass it would be last.
`$a_Detail` is the value of the array at that key - so first pass it would be Joe, last pass it would be Smith.

Typically you see it denoted as `foreach($item as $key=>$value)` - which definitely gives a better representation of what is happening there.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explaination!

Answer (score 4):

The single element of the array may itself be an array.

**Edit:** Also, you're passing the value stored in the array by reference, so whatever you do to $a_detail in the loop will actually alter the value in the array it represents.

Answer (score 3):

with html inputs, you can actually pass arrays to php,

```
<input name="Detail[a]" />
<input name="Detail[b]" />
```